# PHP Simple HTML DOM parser html5

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I can't parse HTML5 element with simple DOM parser : `$html->find( 'header' );` return nothing :/

Have you a solution for parsing html5 DOM with simple DOM parser ? (I use http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/, v1.5, Rev: 210)

Or have you any other parser ? 
( I need to select/extract/remove by HTML tag (div,span,a,img,footer...) or/and by HTML class or/and by HTML id

Thanks ;)

Comment: add more names, around line 1014 on http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/simple_html_dom.php

Comment: Simple HTML DOM is not really a DOM library. The API is completely different. For DOM here is a [HTML5 library](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php). It imports HTML5 as XHTML into a DOM.

Comment: It works for me. Post some source if you want help.

Comment: @dandavis : Thanks, I try `protected $block_tags = array('root'=>1, 'body'=>1, 'form'=>1, 'div'=>1, 'span'=>1, 'table'=>1, 'header'=>1, 'nav'=>1, 'aside'=>1, 'article'=>1, 'footer'=>1);` but didn't work :/

Comment: @pguardiario, I try to parse _for example_ http://html5doctor.com/

Answer (score -1):

Ok, just found why my script doesn't working well, my mistake : didn't read correctly the manual, need more coffe ...
if multiple elements founded => array of objects and I was testing with is_object() on the array...
Really sorry for the noise, gonna tattoo "RTM" on my hand :/

Comment: I hope RTFM == Read The F.. Manual (-: